# Cache-proxy server

Tags: c#, network-programming, httpwebrequest

I'm building a cache proxy server and i was wondering if someone could help me with the cache.  I'm using c#, its just a console application and my cache doesn't seem to work. A tab in a browser will be the client to the proxy server and there should be only a single cache for every client (tab) to access it.

```
public class CacheManager
{
    private static CacheManager _instance;
    private static readonly object _syncLock = new object( );
    private static ObjectCache _currentCache = MemoryCache.Default;

    private CacheManager( )
    {
    }

    public static CacheManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock ( _syncLock )
            {
                if ( _instance == null )
                    _instance = new CacheManager( );
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }


    public bool Contains( string key )
    {
        return _currentCache[ key ] != null;
    }

    public T Get<T>( string key )
    {
        return ( T )_currentCache[ key ];
    }

    public void Add<T>( string key, T data ) where T : class
    {
        if ( data != null )
        {
            var cachePolicy = new CacheItemPolicy
            {
                AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddHours( 1 ),
                SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.Zero
            };

            _currentCache.Add( new CacheItem( key, data ), cachePolicy );
        }
    }

    public void Remove( string key )
    {
        if ( !Contains( key ) ) return;

        _currentCache.Remove( key );
    }

}
```

And here i'm calling it in my Client class:

```
if( cache.Contains( _host ) )
        {
            //Console.WriteLine( "Object in cache! :D" );
            var get = ( String )cache.Get<String>( _host );

            _cacheBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( get );

            ClientSocket.Send( _cacheBuffer );

        }

        else
        {
            Action inv = ( ) => StartTransferToBrowser( );
            inv.Invoke( );
        }
```

Any help would be fine.

Comment: what is your question? / what part "doesn't work"?

Comment: Define the problem better.  Are you getting an exception?

Comment: When i make some request in my browser for the first time, it takes the normal amount to load the page, but when i reload the page for the second time, the proxy server should cache the page and the loading should be reduced. But that is not the case. I'm not getting any exception. I can't post my entire code because its too long.

Comment: What's going on with the immediately executed lambda? Those two lines can be rewritten `StartTransferToBrowser();`.

Comment: @paulRuane I was just trying something else. Indeed, i should just replace it later :)

Comment: based on your code and clarifications this should work. I suggest you write some unit tests to test the behavior of the CacheManager class and/or step through with a debugger

Comment: @BrokenGlass Thanks i will try some tests and see where the problem is taking place.